# Java - binary insertion sort StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to write binary insertion sort in java.

```
    public static int binarySearch(double[] a, int max, int min, double k) {
      if (max == min) 
         return (k > a[min]) ? (min + 1) : min;
      int mid = (max + min) / 2;
      if (k == a[mid])
         return mid;
      else if (k < a[mid])
         return binarySearch(a, mid - 1, min, k);
      else
         return binarySearch(a, max, mid + 1, k);
   }

   public static void binaryInsertionSort(double[] a) {
      // TODO!!!
      for(int i = 1; i < a.length; ++i) {
         int  j = i - 1;
         double tmp = a[i];
         int l = binarySearch(a, j, 0, tmp);
         while(j >= l) {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            --j;
         }
         a[l] = tmp;
      }
   }
```

But when I test it with

```
      a = new double[] {1., 3., 2.};
      DoubleSorting.binaryInsertionSort (a);
```

It returns java.lang.StackOverflowError. I used pretty much the same code in C++, tested it with the same input and it works fine. But I don't know why it doesn't work in Java.

Comment: Which line returns exception?

Comment: this one  `return binarySearch(a, mid - 1, min, k); `  in `binarySearch`

Comment: Okay probably that line causes infinite loop, but I couldn't understand it that good. Please add some comments about what you do, what you want.

Comment: binarySearch will divide my list to 2 parts using the middle element and when i continue to apply binarySearch to those parts at one point, the max value and the min value will be equal and then i compare the value at that place to the value i wanted to insert, I will find the exact place to insert it which is either before or after that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have provided a different example. The stackoverflow error occurs for a sequence like `{4., 3., 2.}`, while `{1., 3., 2.}` does not seem to have an apparent problem.

Running it with the other sequence results in the following calls of your `binarySearch` method:

```
[4.0, 3.0, 2.0], 0, 0, 3.0
[3.0, 4.0, 2.0], 1, 0, 2.0
[3.0, 4.0, 2.0], -1, 0, 2.0
```

After that it just continues with repeating the last call till the stack overflows.
As far as I understand your idea, you do not want to pass -1 here, so you could just change one line:

```
return binarySearch(a, Math.max(0, mid - 1), min, k);
```

Next time you run into such a problem I recommend you to use a debugger, possibly combined with some additional `System.out`'s.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wouldn't have known i had bug in my code without you. I thought it worked fine until i tried implementing it in java.